# How to reset reactive form dropdown in angular 8

Tags: angular8, angular-reactive-forms

Tried to reset dropdown in angular 8 but not working.If i click the reset button i want to show Choose you city but not working.It is coming with empty.How to resolve this issue.

app.component.ts:

```
  reset(){
    his.registrationForm.reset();
  }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-dropdown-reactive-form-4nvza7?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
reset(){
  this.registrationForm.get('cityName').setValue('');
}
```

Comment: Any other way is there?

Comment: Yes, in your HTML `<option value="null" disabled>Choose your city</option>`, initialize your form as `cityName: [null, [Validators.required]]` and then you can do `this.registrationForm.reset();`

Comment: The difference is basically the value you're giving to your form. If you use `something.reset()`, that `something` will get `null` as the value, not `''`, and that last one was the value you were expecting in the form for showing `Choose your city`. I think that's why it wasn't showing that. The way to reset it is just assigning the value you're expecting for showing `Choose your city`.